# How to use DLL name dynamically as part of Import in C#

Tags: c#, dll, import

I want to declare the Import statements for different client dlls in a static class.

Most of the APIs are following the same method signature and for few APIs there is a difference in terms of parameters. I want to do this by using conditional compilation arguments where for the common API the DLL name has to be replcaed with what the user has given in conditional arguments. Project specific Import statements have to be included only if the user has given in the conditional arguments.

Can this be done?

```
namespace Import
{
    static class ClientImport
    {
        public static string DLLNAME;

     #if USERAS

        [DllImport("IDEARASClient.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern Int32 InitilizeClient(String ProtocalSequence,String NetworkAddress,String PortNoString,String TempLogPath,ref Int32 hClient);

     #else
         DLLNAME = "IDEARASClient.dll";
      #endif


    [DllImport(DLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern Int32 InitilizeClient(String 
    ProtocalSequence,String NetworkAddress,String PortNoString,String 
    TempLogPath,ref Int32 hClient);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a handle to your DLL using using LoadLibrary method and then call GetProcAddress to get your desired function address.

Then you'll have to convert the pointer into a function delegate.

An example is given here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jonathanswift/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c/